# Laravel 5.5 using artesaos/defender

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, laravel-5, roles

i'm using laravel 5.5.* and install this https://github.com/artesaos/defender package for roles and permission, all things working fine but when i try to get permission

```
$permissions = array_map(function ($permission) {
        return $permission['name'];
    }, $user->getAllPermissions()->toArray());
```

getting blow error:

`"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError" file : H:\xampp\htdocs\LaraVueAdmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php"
line: 147 message : "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in H:\xampp\htdocs\LaraVueAdmin\vendor\artesaos\defender\src\Defender\Traits\Models\Permission.php on line 75"`

Comment: i find solution by replacing https://github.com/artesaos/defender/blob/master/src/Defender/Traits/Models/Permission.php:75

 with 

`return PermissionUserPivot::fromRawAttributes($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists, $using);`

Answer (score 0):

This solution of Muzafar Ali, worked for me:

I found out the solution by replacing `github.com/artesaos/defender/blob/master/src/Defender/Traits/…`

with

`return PermissionUserPivot::fromRawAttributes($parent, $attributes, 
 $table, $exists, $using);`